# Azure Always Encrypted column encryption key cannot be found by Microsoft JDBC driver for Java after changing encryption key

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, mssql-jdbc, always-encrypted

I am using Java with Spring Framework, connected to a SQL database through Microsoft JDBC Driver.

One of the tables in the database has a column that is encrypted with Azure Always Encrypted. I recently changed the encryption key of the column (decrypted data with old key, encrypted data with new key), and even though the Java service  uses a client who is authenticated to access both column encryption keys, I get the message in the Java application:

> SQL Error: 33294, SQLState: S0004
>
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Some parameters or
>   columns of the batch require to be encrypted, but the corresponding
>   column encryption key cannot be found. Use
>   sp_refresh_parameter_encryption to refresh the module parameters 
>   metadata.

I have tried redeploying the service with no luck. I also tried to run the procedure `sp_refresh_parameter_encryption`, but it requires a module or a stored procedure as parameter, and I don't see any obvious stored procedure to give to it.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that one or more procedures were cached using the old column encryption keys. By running the query

`ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION CLEAR PROCEDURE_CACHE;`

the cache was cleared, the new keys were loaded and everything went fine.

Comment: Just noticed that this also fixed another issue I had one year later in a Java Spring service. After changing encryption type of a column from RANDOMIZED to DETERMINISTIC, I started to get the following errors in my Java code: `Operand type clash: nvarchar(6) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', ...) is incompatible with nvarchar(12) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'RANDOMIZED', ...)`. Restarting the service didn't do anything, but clearing the PROCEDURE_CACHE with the query in the answer solved the issue.